# Ubuntu Server won't boot with “zip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly” error

Tags: ubuntu, vps, ubuntu-10.04, kernel

I am trying to boot lucid server on my new VPS but its giving me some problems. The boot gets to a point where it hangs. At this point it says:

```
No such file `modules-2.6.31-20-server-amd64.tar.bz2'

zip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly

You can use the `bzip2recover' program to attempt to recover data from undamaged sections of corrupted files.

tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Module installation failed.
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I might be able to fix this? Sorry that this is rather vague!

Comment: Where is the VPS hosted? Does the provider have any instructions on how to build the server?

Comment: I'm using GrokThis. You essentially in install one of their distributions from images. It was quite simple to do but I can't seem to work around this problem. The general documentation is here: http://community.grokthis.net/documentation/ManagementCookbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view this looks as if the file "modules-2.6.31-20-server-amd64.tar.bz2" has been compromised. The name indicates that it is used during the userspace boot-part. You could either try to reupload the server image for your vps or try to download-fix-reupload the file:
after a quick look into their reference, i think `instance storage peekfs get` would be the appropriate command.

My guess would be that either the VPS' storage or the server image(possibly during transfer) could have been compromised. Another possible cause could be a failled update of your kernel which caused the zipping of your modules file to fail.

Comment: I've tried re-imaging my VPS several times. I don't really understand what you mean by using that command? I'm quite new to setting these things up...

Comment: if re-imaging didn't solve the problem. either the vps' block storage or the image itself is corrupted. maybe you should contact your hosters' support team?